# How do I eliminate a trailing question mark from my URLs?

Tags: html, forms, url, button

I have set up my buttons as forms because I was lead to believe this is a better practice than wrapping a button with an "a" tag.

```
<form action="contact.html" method="get">
  <button>Contact Us</button>
</form>
```

When clicking the button to go to the contact page, a ? appears at the end. I assumed that was because of method="get", but I removed that code and the question mark still appears.

https://www.website.com/contact.html?
vs
https://www.website.com/contact.html

The pages appear without the ? when linked to using "a" tags, such as from the navigation. The page itself looks fine and functions properly with or without the question mark, but I would like to eliminate it. How can I do that?

Comment: Forms are for collecting information. Don't use them as a substitute for links.

Comment: (Method="GET" is the default and the alternative will badly mess with your caching and ability to use the back button in the browser).

Comment: If you just want something that looks like a button but acts like a link, then use an anchor and CSS to style it to look like a button. No forms, no question marks, no fuss, no muss